# Spring Shell (version:3.1.2) Problem:Can't input Chinese characters by using StringInput component

Tags: spring-shell

Chinese characters disappear in StringInput component and doesn't display in the screen just like I never input it,but it works in traditional command in Spring Shell

I hope this problem can be solved, and the team can add a blinking cursor in StringInput component when input something like traditional command